# Hold time constraint equation

Tags: clock, flipflop, timing, propagation, sequential-logic

I am trying to understand the equation for hold time in the Digital Design and Computer Architecture book: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/hold-time-constraint

Hold time constraint is defined as:

`tccq + tcd ≥ thold`

tccq is the minimum delay from the time the clock rises till the output Q of the flip flop reacts to the rising clock edge.

Similarly tcd is the minimum delay from the time input Q changes till the output D of the combinational logic changes.

1. I am confused about the hold time constraint equation and need some help understanding it - I would expect `thold ≥ tccq`, as Q will not react before `tccq` and a `thold ≥ tccq` would ensure that Q has reacted to the input.
2. Moreover, according to the constraint equation, `thold` cannot be greater than `tccq + tcd`, but I don't understand why can't `thold` be greater than `tccq + tcd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tccq is a characteristic of the first flip-flop and it means that after the rising edge, its output  will change after tccq.

thold is a characteristic of the second flip-flop and it means that after the same rising edge, its input must remain stable for thold so that its output can have the time to be refreshed (setup).

tcd is the delay induced by the combinatorial logic between the output of the first flip-flop and the input of the second flip-flop.

At the rising edge of the clock (assumed the same for both flip-flops) the second flip-flop must refresh before its input changes which means its thold must not exceed tccq + tcd.

Comment: "tccq is a characteristic of the first flip-flop" and "thold is a characteristic of the second flip-flop" - these two statements helped me understand this equation. I was confused because I was relating both, the tccq and thold to the first flip flop